# When I use select tag in my Vue app, the drop-down-icon is disappeared. (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm developing a Vue.js application with Vuetify. But when I use a select tag, the drop-down-icon is disappeared.

```
<template>
    <select class="select">
        <option
            v-for="item items"
            :key="item"
        >{{item}}</option>
    </select>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        items:['apple', 'tomato']
    }),
};
</script>

<style>
.select {
    border-radius: '3px';
    border: '1px solid #333333';
    padding-left: '3px';
}
</style>
```

[image]

But when I test pure HTML code in a Chrome, I can see the drop-down icon.

```
<select>
    <option> apple</option>
    <option> tomato</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I guess that the Vuetify changed CSS style of my app. How can I make the icon appears?

I can't use . Because v-select is too big. I need a small height select box. That's why I use vanilla select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the element you'll see that vuetify adds `apperance: none` which removes the carot/arrow.

But if you're using vuetify than use its [select element](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects):

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
></v-select>
```

And choose the appropriate theme or style it with your custom styles.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: ['apple', 'tomato']
  }
})
```

```css
.select {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  padding-left: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist !important; /* override vuetify style */
  -moze-appearance: menulist !important; /* override vuetify style */
  appearance: menulist !important; /* override vuetify style */
  margin-bottom: 2rem; /* demo purpose */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select class="select">
    <option v-for="item in items" :key="item">{{item}}</option>
  </select>

  <v-select :items="items" :label="items"></v-select>
</div>
```